# Stripe payment to customer

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

Me and my team, are trying to build a `upwork` type online marketplace. BusinessUser post job and customer bid for job. After winning job, he/she will complete job. If job complete he/she will get paid. We're using `stripe` for payment. We received money from BusinessUser using stripe. We have already develop that part. After complete job, customer will get paid. My problem is, how can we do this?

NB: we are using node.js for development.

Comment: That's a very broad question, but yes, this can absolutely be done, using [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect). It's a complex product so it's better to read through all the docs and experiment with it in Stripe's test mode.

Comment: But as far as I know, `stripe connect` is not available to all country

Comment: Some features are not supported in some countries, but Connect in general should be supported if you've already got a Stripe account. If your county is not supported yet, you can register interest/be notified by signing up at https://stripe.com/global. But the only way to pay out to a customer in the way you describe, using Stripe, is to use Stripe Connect, yes.